# Flink, differences between TableResult#print and DataStream#print

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using Flink 1.14, for the code snippet below, if I want to print the result, it seems both TableResult#print and DataStream#print can be used, but I do see different behavior between them, TableResult#print prints the result every 3 minutes, this seems to be related to checkpoint interval. While DataStream#print prints the result every 10 seconds. I'm curious to know what happens underneath?

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = ...;
env.setParallelism(1);
env.enableCheckpointing(3 * 60000);
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = ...;
// the mock source produces one message every 10 seconds
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple3<Integer, String, Integer>> ds = ...;
Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(ds, schema);

// this prints every 3 minutes
tableEnv.createTemporaryView("foobar", table);
tableEnv.executeSql("select f0, f1, f2 from foobar").print();

// this prints every 10 seconds
//tableEnv.toDataStream(table).print();
//env.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While DataStream#print prints the result every 10 seconds. I'm curious to know what happens underneath?

This is because [`DataStream.print()`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/0915c9850d861165e283acc0f60545cd836f0567/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.java#L940-L954) actually treats the printing operation as a sink:

```
/**
 * Writes a DataStream to the standard output stream (stdout).
 *
 * <p>For each element of the DataStream the result of {@link Object#toString()} is written.
 *
 * <p>NOTE: This will print to stdout on the machine where the code is executed, i.e. the Flink
 * worker.
 *
 * @return The closed DataStream.
 */
@PublicEvolving
public DataStreamSink<T> print() {
    PrintSinkFunction<T> printFunction = new PrintSinkFunction<>();
    return addSink(printFunction).name("Print to Std. Out");
}
```

So you are seeing a result written out every ten seconds because you are generating a new message to the stream at the same rate. The message passes through your stream and is eventually written to the sink, which just prints out to standard output.

> TableResult#print prints the result every 3 minutes, this seems to be related to checkpoint interval.

You are correct in this as well, if you take a look at [`TableResult.print()`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/237cec31e6d8b70c2b9a0f939c7a8a2b04c24568/flink-table/flink-table-api-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/api/TableResult.java#L203-L228), it's very closely tied to the checkpointing interval as defined in the interface below:

```
/**
 * Print the result contents as tableau form to client console.
 *
 * <p>This method has slightly different behaviors under different checkpointing settings (to
 * enable checkpointing for a streaming job, set checkpointing properties through {@link
 * TableConfig}).
 *
 * <ul>
 *   <li>For batch jobs or streaming jobs without checkpointing, this method has neither
 *       exactly-once nor at-least-once guarantee. Query results are immediately accessible by
 *       the clients once they're produced, but exceptions will be thrown when the job fails and
 *       restarts.
 *   <li>For streaming jobs with exactly-once checkpointing, this method guarantees an
 *       end-to-end exactly-once record delivery. A result will be accessible by clients only
 *       after its corresponding checkpoint completes.
 *   <li>For streaming jobs with at-least-once checkpointing, this method guarantees an
 *       end-to-end at-least-once record delivery. Query results are immediately accessible by
 *       the clients once they're produced, but it is possible for the same result to be
 *       delivered multiple times.
 * </ul>
 *
 * <p>In order to fetch result to local, you can call either {@link #collect()} and {@link
 * #print()}. But, they can't be called both on the same {@link TableResult} instance, because
 * the result can only be accessed once.
 */
void print();
```